# Embed Facebook group activity in website works for some groups but not others?

Tags: facebook

I want to show activity of the group Suburban Cyclists Unlimited (ID 23950916762) on my club's website (suburbancyclists.org). I found exactly what I want on a Clemson University site (http://www.clemson.edu/public/web/cascade_how-to/advanced/facebook_wall_feed.html), but it does not work with some groups. I created a test page with examples at [suburbancyclists.org/fbtest.htm](http://suburbancyclists.org/fbtest.htm).  Any idea why this does not work with the SCU ID or if there is another way to do this? Thanks.

Here's the embedded html.  Just substitute group ID to try others.

Comment: It appears you left out actually including the embedded HTML?

Comment: Strange. I thought it was there when I pushed the Post button.   <iframe allowtransparency="true" height="240" scrolling="no" src="http://www.facebook.com/connect/connect.php?id=1584910641723091&amp;connections=0&amp;stream=1" style="border: 1px; width: 300; height: 380px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px; float: right;" width="320" ></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward, the embedded plugin is only for **fan pages** not groups.

This -> `https://www.facebook.com/groups/23950916762` is a group
This -> `https://www.facebook.com/carolinacanning` is a page.

Comment: Thanks.  I stumbled onto Pages after posting, then saw that only the Pages got through.  Does FB explicitly state anywhere that Groups are not supported by this?

Comment: @SCUTechnology https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages "The Like Box is a special version of the Like Button designed only for Facebook Pages. It allows admins to promote their Pages and embed a simple feed of content from a Page into other sites."